# Name mangling for nested Master Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I use asp.net 4 and C#.

I have some nested Master Pages; I display in my Content Page a list of Links using a repeater.

This is a sample of code generated by ASP.NET as read in the Source code in the Browser.

As you can see the **ID is very lengthy**.

My question:

- How can I have control on the ID generated, so I can chose another format much shorter?
  Please keep in mind that I cannot get rid of Master Pages for my layout.

Thanks for your help on this!

---

```
<li>
<a id="ContentBody_ContentColumn2_latestArticle_uxRepeaterLatestArticles_uxLink_0" href="Category.aspx?CategoryId=8">AAAAA</a>
</li>

<li>
<a id="ContentBody_ContentColumn2_latestArticle_uxRepeaterLatestArticles_uxLink_1" href="Category.aspx?CategoryId=12">BBBBB</a>
</li>
```

I would like instead an ID like:

> ID="CB_CC_LA_R_0"
>
> ID="CB_CC_LA_R_1"

Useful article:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx
http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the asp:HyperLink with plain HTML anchor tag and use following markup for it:

```
<a id='CB_CC_LA_R_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' href='<%# Eval("IndexPropertyName", "Category.aspx?CategoryId={0}") %>' >
    <%# Eval("TextPopertyName") %>
</a>
```

Comment: What about using ClientIdMode?

Comment: Sure if you are using 4th framework yo may use it. Just set ClientIDMode on repeater to Static and on hyperlinks to Predictable